# How to do an efficient join grouped aggrgation in Spark?

Tags: python, apache-spark

I'm trying to do the following operation using Apache Spark in Python:

1. Join three dataframes (one big, two small) on a set of keys.
2. Group rows by a different keys.
3. Take the product of two columns.
4. Get the total of that product for each group.

I can do this in a few minutes using Pandas and manual parallelism, but I haven't gotten this to run in a reasonable amount of time in Spark.

To be more specific, I have:

1. Big dataframe (400 million rows) with keys Date, X, Y, and Value.
2. Small dataframe (3000 rows) with keys Date, Z.
3. Smallish dataframe (1 million rows) with X, Z, W, and Weight.

I'd like to join these Dataframes on Date, X, and Z; group by Date, W and Y; then take the sum of Value * Weight for each group. I'm running an AWS EC2 r5a.16xlarge with 64 cores and 500GB of memory.

The simplest version of my attempt to do this looks like:

```
import pyspark.sql
import pyspark.sql.functions as sqlf

# spark setup
spark = (
    pyspark.sql.SparkSession
     .builder
     .master("local[*]")
     .config("spark.executor.memory", "450g")
     .config("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "10g")
     .config("spark.driver.memory", "450g")
     .config("spark.memory.offHeap.enabled",True)
     .config("spark.memory.offHeap.size","400g")
     .getOrCreate()
)
```

...

```
result = big_df.join(
    date_to_z.hint('broadcast'),
    on = 'date',
).join(
    weights_df.hint('broadcast'),
    on = (
        (date_to_text_date.z == flat_weights.z)
        & (features_loaded.x == flat_weights.x)
    )
).withColumn(
    'weighted_value',
    big_df.value * weights_df.weight
).groupby(
    big_df.date, big_df.y, weights_df.w
).agg(
    sqlf.sum('weighted_value')
)
```

The progress bars show it getting to a stage where is shows (0 + 64) / 67 and hangs; it then fills up all of the system memory and crashes. (The dataframes easily fit in memory using Pandas). I have looked at the Spark dashboard but I can't really tell what it's getting caught on. Here's the DAG for the stage:

[image: DAG for hung Spark Stage]

I have tried many variations to try to get it run efficiently, including:

- Sorting, repartitioning, and bucketing the big Dataframe
- Broadcasting the smaller dataframes on the join (shown above)
- Doing the aggregation in the RDD interface with reduceByKey
- Doing the aggregation manually with treeReduce

Nothing I've tried has seemed to make much of a difference; it either hangs, crashes, or uses up all the system memory. I think one of the following has to be true:

- This is not in fact the kind of thing Spark is meant for.
- Spark requires a lot of nontrivial tuning and expertise to use efficiently.
- I'm missing something obvious about the correct way to do this in Spark.

Comment: how many instances?

Comment: just one instance

Comment: reduce memory setup 1/16, the number of executors might be 16 and the option is for an executor I guess.

Comment: Can you edit your question to add the error + stack trace you're getting?